# how to create images thumbnails and insert into database using php?

Tags: php, mysql, thumbnails, image-uploading

hi
  I want to create  3 different size thumbnails of  image using php and want to store into db so that I could retrieve them. how to do that? user will upload image and 3 different size thumbnails will be generated and store into database. please guide.

Regards
      Touseef

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a thumbnail library like phpthumb

please see samples here:

http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/demo/demo/phpThumb.demo.demo.php

Comment: phpthumb can use imagemagick too.  if you don't have imagemagick and GD and this is not on a server you have root access to it, then I would suggest changing hosting service .